# How to recover the password of prestashop?

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I clicked on forgot password link and wrote my email but the server
didn't send any information regarding password to my mail-id.I have
used the following query which causes an error .Please rectify the
error..

```
UPDATE 'ps_employee'
SET 'passwd' = md5(“<3w3kuJFFAMFB4zUR19aTDvbnomepQJFTd60NUCns5HDtqf9mEkv6APFy><samyak02>”) 
WHERE 'email' = “<abhijain.cse@gmail.com>”;
```

where, `3w3kuJFFAMFB4zUR19aTDvbnomepQJFTd60NUCns5HDtqf9mEkv6APFy` is the
cookie_key in settings.inc.php and `samyak02` is the new password I want
to set.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ps_employee' SET 'passwd' = md5(â€œ<3w3kuJFFAMFB4zUR19aTDvbnomepQJFTd60NUCns5HD' at line 1

Comment: Hmm, md5. This is potentially recoverable (well, you'll find a collision, but not necessarily your password) within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Register a new user/employee
2. Go to the user table, copy hashed password
3. Go to employee table, save your hashed password (just in case);
4. Paste hashed password of newly registered user into your 
   user row (replace your hash)
5. Since PS uses the same hashing algorithm, this should do the trick.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The correct query is:

```
UPDATE `ps_employee`
SET `passwd` = md5('3w3kuJFFAMFB4zUR19aTDvbnomepQJFTd60NUCns5HDtqf9mEkv6APFysamyak02') 
WHERE `email` = 'abhijain.cse@gmail.com';
```

3w3kuJFFAMFB4zUR19aTDvbnomepQJFTd60NUCns5HDtqf9mEkv6APFy is your _COOKIE_KEY_ from /config/settings.inc.php

samyak02 is the new password.

abhijain.cse@gmail.com is the email address of the Employee you want to change password.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have phpMyAdmin it's even easier:**

1. Get the cookie-key from */config/settings.inc.php*
2. Open PhpMyAdmin and find the table *ps_employee*  in the correct database (check above settings.inc.php if you are unsure).
3. Find the employee you want to change password for and click edit
4. Find the field *passwd*. Paste cookie-key and write your password directly after. Example f4m8fu983mfu9348mfu3489mfu3498mf98u3grMYPASSW0rD123
5. Before you click *GO* to finish, you **must** select *md5* under *Functions* dropdown menu.
6. Login to back-office :)

PS: Your table might be named something other than ps_employee, like brg_employee or r23r_employee. It depends what *prefix* your prestashop has. Again, this is found in the *settings.inc.php*

PS2: For your learning process I recommend taking a look at the SQL-query that show up after you click GO when inside PhpMyAdmin. It's a great tool to learn SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

*As everybody can see the resetting admin password via SQL execution is very hard for the most of users and they make mistakes when performing this task and do not understanding what they doing.*

So, if there no way to recover a password by default recovery form the easiest way is to **recover password by [this free tool for PrestaShop](https://prestashop.modulez.ru/en/tools-scripts/54-prestashop-password-recovery-tool.html), because, no knowledge is required about database and programming**. Required the access to a site folder, for example, FTP access or the web access to an admin panel with file manager.

**How to use.**

1. Download zip-archive with the [last stable release of the script](https://prestashop.modulez.ru/upload/prestashop-password-recovery-tool.zip) ([mirror](https://github.com/zapalm/prestashop-password-recovery-tool/releases)).
2. Unpack the archive and copy `prestashop-password-recovery-tool.php` file to the root of your PrestaShop installation directory.
3. Run the tool by URL, for example, `http://example.com/prestashop-password-recovery-tool.php`, where `example.com` is your site domain. You will see the form to input your admin e-mail and a new password.
4. Submit the password recovery form.
5. After recovery, delete the file of the script.

*This tool is also compatible with ThirtyBees (the fork of PrestaShop).*